# How do I filter an array of Strings to a unique result in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to filter `[String]` with many items with similar characters to the `searchString`.  But I want to end up with a result that only returns an item that exactly matches the character length of the `searchString` and doesn't return all items that contain the `searchString`.

I've tried many options including .map .filter .contains but am not able to isolate the item only to the `searchString`.

```
func filterWaypoint(searchString: String, array: [String]) -> String {
    let result = array.filter({(item: String) -> Bool in
        let stringMatch = item.localizedLowercase.range(of: searchString.localizedLowercase)
        return stringMatch != nil ? true : false
    })
    print(result)
    return result[0]
}
```

`searchString = "POM"` which is returning:

```
["I JIPOM 384824N 1211336W \'ZOA CA K2 WAYPOIN", 
 "I JOPOM 441716N 0930727W \'ZMP MN K3 WAYPOIN", 
 "I POM   340442N 1174713W \'ZLA CA    VORTAC", 
 "I POMBE 353632N 1090611W \'ZAB AZ K2 WAYPOIN", 
 "I POMDE 293941N 0945039W \'ZHU TX K4 WAYPOIN", 
 "I POMEE 364451N 1075716W \'ZDV NM K2 REP-PT", 
 "I POMHO 322104N 0952337W \'ZFW TX K4 WAYPOIN", 
 "I POMIE 335738N 0810509W \'ZJX SC K7 WAYPOIN".... etc.]
```

The item I want to return is the THIRD item in the above result:

```
"I POM   340442N 1174713W \'ZLA CA    VORTAC"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use Regular Expression to search for word boundaries

```
func filterWaypoint(searchString: String, array: [String]) -> String {
    let result = array.filter { $0.range(of: "\\b\(searchString)\\b", options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }
    print(result)
    return result.first ?? ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be more than one result, so I changed the return type to an array, nut you can get the `first` element of it if you need to.

```
func filterWaypoint(searchString: Substring, array: [String]) -> [String] {
    return array.filter { $0.split(separator: " ").contains(searchString) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate each item to words using `split` function, and check if one of the words equals to your `searchString`. like that:

```
array.filter { item -> Bool in
    item.split(separator: " ")
        .map { String($0) }
        .contains { work -> Bool in
            word.lowercased() == searchString.lowercased()
    }
}.first
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem by using Regular Expression.

```
extension String {
    func contains(word : String) -> Bool {
        let regex = "\\b\(word)\\b"
        return self.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) != nil
    }
}
```

For example:

```
    var arr = ["swift", "if", "gif", "niff"]

    arr = arr.filter { (string) -> Bool in
        string.contains(word: "if")
    }

    print(arr)
```

Result: ["if"]